# How to fix npm package braces issue with react-scripts v2.1.5 when npm audit does nothing?

Tags: npm, jestjs, braces, react-scripts

My NPM package in my react client folder is giving me 63 low vulnerabilities all dealing with the braces package mainly in the jest folder of the react-scripts package of version 2.1.5. NPM Audit fix doesn't work, what do I do?

I've tried downgrading to previous versions of react-scripts, updating braces either through updating the package.json, deleting the package lock, and running npm install again, or running npm update braces, but nothing has worked after 2 hours of fiddling. I've also tried to revert to a previous version of my Github package.json when it was working. I believe it stopped working after I tried to download firebase-ui, but I think it has to do with updating the packages since I've deleted the node modules and npm installing several times.

Here's what my clean package.json that's messing up.

```
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
"@babel/core": "*",
"axios": "*",
"body-parser": "*",
"bootstrap": "*",
"cors": "*",
"dotenv": "*",
"draft-js": "*",
"draft-js-export-html": "*",
"errorhandler": "*",
"express": "*",
"express-session": "*",
"history": "*",
"jquery": "*",
"moment": "*",
"mongoose": "*",
"morgan": "*",
"node-sass-chokidar": "*",
"npm-run-all": "*",
"path": "*",
"query-string": "*",
"react": "*",
"react-dom": "*",
"react-loadable": "*",
"react-redux": "*",
"react-router-dom": "*",
"react-router-redux": "*",
"react-scripts": "*",
"react-validation": "*",
"reactstrap": "*",
"recharts": "*",
"redux": "*",
"redux-logger": "*",
"redux-observable": "*",
"redux-thunk": "*",
"rxjs": "*",
"rxjs-compat": "*",
"validator": "*"
```

And here's the issue I'm getting:

Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

Package         braces

Dependency of   react-scripts

Path            react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > micromatch > braces

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/786

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran `npm install braces@2.3.1` and then `npm update`

That still resulted in the 63 vulnerabilities but it did bring my braces to the current version. So I went through and updated ALL references of `braces` in the `package-lock.json` to `2.3.2`. I then ran `npm update` again and when I ran `npm audit` the vulnerabilities were gone.

Comment: Are there any semver breaking changes issue as the npm audit suggests there could be?

Comment: I followed these instructions and updated via `npm update` after and the warning disappeared for me as well

Comment: I did that with no success :(

Comment: -1 for suggestion of editing package-lock.json
@Jony It works but you should NOT be doing this. It's a generated file for a reason.

Comment: @Emobe Then, what's your suggestion?

Comment: @Jony My suggestion is to NOT edit package-lock.json

Answer (score 4):

Jest is a test package and will never appear in you production bundle, you can ignore this vulnerability without risks.

This package https://github.com/naugtur/npm-audit-resolver#readme can help you to ignore low vulnerabilities.

Comment: Although it won't affect production code, vulnerabilities in the developer dependencies might still affect your developers or build process.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve similar issue with `resolutions` field followed by `yarn install` -

```
  "resolutions": {
    "braces": "= 2.3.1"
  }
```

I've inspected `yarn.lock` and verified that only relevant dependency was updated.

There is more on the topic here - https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4986.